# Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable to authenticate users

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm starting with the Zend framework and I wanted to use Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable to authenticate my users ...

I looked at the docs, which seem quite straight forward, but I'm getting an error.

Here's my code snippet :

```
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($this->_dbAdapter, 'users', 'username', 'password', 'MD5(?)');
```

I have a 'users' table with the 'username' and 'password' columns, but each time I run

```
$result = $adapter->authenticate();
```

I get an application error :

```
Message: The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
```

Could anyone help me with this? I just want a basic authentication (the passwords are encrypted using md5)

The weird thing is that the following works ...

```
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($this->_dbAdapter); $adapter->setTableName('users') ->setIdentityColumn('username') ->setCredentialColumn('password') ->setIdentity($username) ->setCredential(md5($password));
```

but why does the "setCredentialTreatment" (or using it as in the first code snippet) method fail ...

is it because i'm using sqlite3 and not mySQL???

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it. For using `MD5()` in SQLite you need Tcllib and Trf.